# How to make a button go to another page?

Tags: android

Okay so I have a section_home layout that has this button code.

```
<Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:text="Apply"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

What I want is when someone click's that "Apply" button for it to go to my other layout that's called section_apply

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/window_bg"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/launcherslist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/light_bg"
    android:divider="@color/transparent" />
```

Here is my java class for my home layout its called HomeFragment.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Button button;

    private static final String MARKET_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";

    private String PlayStoreDevAccount, PlayStoreListing, AppOnePackage, AppTwoPackage, AppThreePackage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_home, container, false);

        PlayStoreDevAccount = getResources().getString(R.string.play_store_dev_link);
        PlayStoreListing = getActivity().getPackageName();
        AppOnePackage = getResources().getString(R.string.app_one_package);
        AppTwoPackage = getResources().getString(R.string.app_two_package);
        AppThreePackage = getResources().getString(R.string.app_three_package);

        ActionBar toolbar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }


        ObservableScrollView content = (ObservableScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.HomeContent);

        TextView ratebtn = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.rate_button);
        ratebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent rate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MARKET_URL + PlayStoreListing));
                startActivity(rate);
            }
        });


        //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.apply_btn);
        //fab.setColorNormal(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        //fab.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_pressed));
        //fab.setColorRipple(getResources().getColor(R.color.semitransparent_white));
        //fab.show(true);
        //fab.attachToScrollView(content);

        //fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //  @Override
        //public void onClick(View v) {
        //  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).result.setSelectionByIdentifier(3);
        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchFragment(3, getResources().getString(R.string.section_three), "Apply");
        //  }
        //});

        return root;
    }

    private boolean AppIsInstalled(String packageName)
    {
        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        boolean installed;
        try
        {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            installed = false;
        }
        return installed;
    }
}
```

This is my java class for the apply layout called ApplyFragment

```
public class ApplyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String MARKET_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";

    private String intentString;
    private final List<Launcher> launchers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_apply, container, false);

        // Splits all launcher arrays by the | delimiter {name}|{package}
        String[] launcherArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.launchers);
        for (String launcher : launcherArray)
            launchers.add(new Launcher(launcher.split("\\|")));

        ActionBar toolbar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (toolbar != null)
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.section_three);

        ListView launcherslist = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.launcherslist);

        LaunchersAdapter adapter = new LaunchersAdapter(launchers);
        launcherslist.setAdapter(adapter);
        launcherslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (launchers.get(position).name.equals("Google Now Launcher"))
                    gnlDialog();
                else if (LauncherIsInstalled(launchers.get(position).packageName))
                    openLauncher(launchers.get(position).name);
                else
                    openInPlayStore(launchers.get(position));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    private boolean LauncherIsInstalled(String packageName) {
        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        boolean installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            installed = false;
        }
        return installed;
    }


    private void openLauncher(String name) {

        final String className = "com.jahirfiquitiva.paperboard" + ".launchers."
                + Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0))
                + name.substring(1).toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").replace("launcher", "")
                + "Launcher";

        Class<?> cl = null;
        try {
            cl = Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("LAUNCHER CLASS MISSING", "Launcher class for: '" + name + "' missing!");
        }
        if (cl != null) {
            Constructor<?> constructor = null;
            try {
                constructor = cl.getConstructor(Context.class);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.e("LAUNCHER CLASS CONS",
                        "Launcher class for: '" + name + "' is missing a constructor!");
            }
            try {
                if (constructor != null)
                    constructor.newInstance(getActivity());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openInPlayStore(final Launcher launcher) {
        intentString = MARKET_URL + launcher.packageName;
        final String LauncherName = launcher.name;
        final String cmName = "CM Theme Engine";
        String dialogContent;

        if (LauncherName.equals(cmName)) {
            dialogContent = launcher.name + getResources().getString(R.string.cm_dialog_content);
            intentString = "http://download.cyanogenmod.org/";
        } else {
            dialogContent = launcher.name + getResources().getString(R.string.lni_content);
            intentString = MARKET_URL + launcher.packageName;
        }

        new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title(launcher.name + getResources().getString(R.string.lni_title))
                .content(dialogContent)
                .positiveText(R.string.lni_yes)
                .negativeText(R.string.lni_no)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intentString));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    public class Launcher {

        public final String name;
        public final String packageName;

        public Launcher(String[] values) {
            name = values[0];
            packageName = values[1];
        }
    }

    class LaunchersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Launcher> {

        final List<Launcher> launchers;

        LaunchersAdapter(List<Launcher> launchers) {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.item_launcher, R.id.launchername, launchers);
            this.launchers = launchers;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View item = convertView;
            LauncherHolder holder;

            if (item == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_launcher, parent, false);
                holder = new LauncherHolder(item);
                item.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (LauncherHolder) item.getTag();

            }
            // Turns Launcher name "Something Pro" to "l_something_pro"
            int iconResource = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(
                    "ic_" + launchers.get(position).name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_"),
                    "drawable",
                    getActivity().getPackageName()
            );

            holder.icon.setImageResource(iconResource);
            holder.launchername.setText(launchers.get(position).name);

            if (LauncherIsInstalled(launchers.get(position).packageName)) {
                holder.isInstalled.setText(R.string.installed);
                holder.isInstalled.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            } else {
                holder.isInstalled.setText(R.string.noninstalled);
                holder.isInstalled.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

            return item;
        }

        class LauncherHolder {

            final ImageView icon;
            final TextView launchername;
            final TextView isInstalled;

            LauncherHolder(View v) {
                icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.launchericon);
                launchername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.launchername);
                isInstalled = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.launcherinstalled);
            }
        }
    }

    private void gnlDialog() {
        final String appLink = MARKET_URL + getResources().getString(R.string.extraapp);
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title(R.string.gnl_title)
                .content(R.string.gnl_content)
                .positiveText(R.string.lni_yes)
                .negativeText(R.string.lni_no)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                              @Override
                              public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                                  super.onPositive(dialog);
                                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                  intent.setData(Uri.parse(appLink));
                                  startActivity(intent);
                              }
                          }
                ).show();
    }
}
```

Basically what I want is for the button in the home layout to take you to this ApplyFragment/section_apply layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the Paperboard template, correct? This code should work for you without issue if you place it in your HomeFragment and the id of your button is "button".

```
        TextView btn = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).result.setSelectionByIdentifier(3);
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchFragment(3, getResources().getString(R.string.section_three), "Apply");
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Changed to work perfectly with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onClickListener:

```
 ApplyFragment applyFrag = new ApplyFragment();
 this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag, TAG_FRAGMENT)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();
```